# Octave code to plot labeled data

Tags: matlab, plot, octave, svm

Good afternoon, guys. I'm learning SVM and try to finish an exercise at [openclassroom.stanford.edu](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex7/ex7.html).

My question is: What is the **Octave/Matlab code to plot** as follows
[image]

If I have a set of **2D feature points**

{(x_11, x_12), (x_21, x_22), ..., (x_i1, x_i2)},

and the corresponding **labels** set is

{1, -1, ..., -1 },

what is the **code to plot** those data in a 2D manner as in that picture?

I would like to make (x_i1, x_i2) correspond to 1 (or -1, whatever).

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a vector of x-coordinates `X`, and y-coordinates `Y`, and an indicator vector `k` of 1's and -1's, you could do

```
plot(X(k>0),Y(k>0),'b',X(k<0),Y(k<0),'g')
```

which uses logical indexing to pick out the elements with `k=1` and `k=-1` separately, or use `scatter` and use the `k` vector to colour the points. I set the `colormap` to have blue (`k=-1`) and green (`k=1`) points.

```
colormap([0 0 1;0 1 0])
scatter(X,Y,[],k,'filled')
```

Using `plot`: (to be fair you could change the markers to filled dots as well)
[image]

and `scatter`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, which works ...

```
X = [2 2;3 4;0.5 4;3 6;5 7;7 8;6 8]
y = [0;0;0;0;1;1;1]
plot(X(y>0,1), X(y>0,2), 'rs','MarkerFaceColor', 'r', 'MarkerSize', 27, X(y==0,1), X(y==0,2),'go', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'g', 'MarkerSize', 27)
axis([0 10 0 10])
```

Result:

[image]